# EF 4.0 - CodeFirst One To Many - Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}


public class Trip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, a Trip can have 1 or more Persons...

I tried to use the EntityConfiguration to build the database properly but I cannot manage to make it work... I am quite confused on its usage:

```
public class TripConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Trip>
{
    internal TripConfiguration()
    {
        // ???

    }
}
```

What do I need to write to have the application to behave properly:

1. I need at least one person.
2. I might have more that one person
3. A person cannot be in the SAME trip twice
4. A person can be in more than one trip

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Person)
            .WithMany(x => x.Trips)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.PersonId);
```

Your classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips { get; set;}
}


public class Trip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

And as far that I know, EF doesn't support unique FK (or correct me if I'm wrong..). So you have to check it yourself.

Comment: I edited my question. A person can be cannot be in the same trip more than once. But a person can be in multiple trip.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a One-To-Many relationship, this is a Many-To-Many relationship, you need to have collections on both sides of the relationship. EF will create the joiner table on your behalf. Since today you cannot configure a person being in a trip only once you will need to create a unique constraint in your joiner table once is created to assure this happens since EF does not yet support Unique Key constraints through configuration.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
}


public class Trip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfiguration()
    {
         this.HasMany(t => t.Trips).WithMany(t => t.Persons);
    }
}
```